# Required JSF input component which is hidden by JavaScript is still validated

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a list of values from ,from the list of values i want to check some values means at that corressponding text box will show in bottom.Otherwise the text box will be hidden.I have done this process using javascript. But my issues is i have to validate  using required=true attribute. But the problem is the hidden text box also validated.

Primefaces pages for List values:

```
     <p:selectManyCheckbox onchange="checkValue();" value="#{volunteerBean.knowAbt}" layout="pageDirection" id="s" immediate="true" required="true" requiredMessage="Select how to konws about cv?" style="width:300px;height:170px;">
     <f:selectItems value="#{volunteerBean.hearLst}" var="he"  itemLabel="#{he}" itemValue="#{he}" />
     <p:ajax event="change" update="msg1111" />
     </p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Input Text Box coding:

```
    <p:inputText style="display:none;" id="searchEngine" value="#{volunteerBean.searchEngine}"><p:watermark for="searchEngine" value="Search Engine"/>
```

JavaScript for hidden and show inputText through checking the list of checkBox:

```
    function checkValue() {
    var chk = document.getElementById("volunteerForm:s:10");
             if (chk1.checked) {
            document.getElementById('volunteerForm:searchEngine').style.display='';
            }else {
    document.getElementById('volunteerForm:searchEngine').style.display='none';
            }
        }
```

I am using primefaces 3.0  and jsf 2.0. How to solve it

Answer (score 2):

You're changing only the HTML DOM tree and you're not changing the JSF component tree. JSF is not aware at all that the HTML element has been hidden in the client side. You need to show/hide the JSF component instead by its `rendered` attribute and include its client ID in the `<p:ajax update>`.

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox ... value="#{volunteerBean.knowAbt}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{volunteerBean.hearLst}" />
    <p:ajax event="change" update="msg1111 searchEngine" />
</p:selectManyCheckbox>

<p:inputText id="searchEngine" ... rendered="#{volunteerBean.knowAbt.contains('valueOfItem10')}" />
```

where `valueOfItem10` is the exact value of the item at index 10, like as you tried to check in JS. Note that I assume that `knowAbt` is a `List<String>`, exactly as your `hearLst` suggests (for which I have removed the superfluous `var`, `itemLabel` and `itemValue` from the above example as they are the defaults already). Otherwise you'd need to perform the job in a helper method of the backing bean instead.